# Joining Relationships On Entity SubClasses in Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine, dql

I have two entities that share an abstract class creating class table inheritance. I can query for the entities by using the abstract class' repository and get all the entities that extend the abstract class as the result.

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
    ->where('c.featured = true')
    ->orderBy('c.sticky', 'DESC')
    ->addOrderBy('c.weight', 'ASC')
    ->setFirstResult($offset)
    ->setMaxResults($limit);

// Returns 8 results, results in 34 queries
```

The sub classes contain ManyToMany relationships to other entities so if I query in this manner, those relationships result in additional queries since they are not being joined. How can you query for entities extending an abstract class and join their columns? I tried adding multiple from statements with left joins but the query returned fewer than the expected 8 results. That query builder looks something like this:

```
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select(array(
    'a', 'artist', 'country', 
    't', 'artwork', 'user'))
   ->from('AcmeArtworkBundle:Artwork', 'a')
   ->from('AcmeTourBundle:Tour', 't')
   ->leftJoin('a.artist', 'artist')
   ->leftJoin('a.country', 'country')
   ->leftJoin('t.artwork', 'artwork')
   ->leftJoin('t.user', 'user')
   ->where('a.featured = true')
   ->andWhere('t.featured = true')
   ->orderBy('a.sticky', 'DESC')
   ->addOrderBy('t.sticky', 'DESC')
   ->addOrderBy('a.weight', 'ASC')
   ->addOrderBy('t.weight', 'ASC')
   ->setFirstResult($offset)
   ->setMaxResults($limit);

// 5 results :-(
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the information provided by the link provided by @Ocramius, By default Doctrine loads entities using lazy loading. Associations are fetched only when they need to be. You can tell Doctrine to automatically fetch an association by setting the fetch mode to EAGER.

```
/**
 * @var string $date
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Date", inversedBy="artwork", cascade={"persist"}, fetch="EAGER")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="date", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $date;
```

It's important to note that you can actually cause more queries to be run by doing this if you aren't careful.

Comment: Fetching eagerly isn't always the correct solution, since the ORM won't always be able to add all the necessary joins to the SQL used to fetch your objects.

Comment: Yes, this is an important point. It's not a one size fits all solution, it worked out in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [fetch join](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#joins) and Doctrine ORM's [Paginator](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/8a29d91d1550eca3ac7677a34a661e708cf553f4/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/Pagination/Paginator.php) as described in the [documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/pagination.html):

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('c', 'd')
    ->from('MyInheritanceClass', 'c')
    ->join('c.d', 'd')
    ->where('c.featured = true')
    ->orderBy('c.sticky', 'DESC')
    ->addOrderBy('c.weight', 'ASC')
    ->setFirstResult($offset)
    ->setMaxResults($limit);

$paginator = new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination($qb);

var_dump(count($paginator)); // 8 results, 2 queries
```

Comment: I don't think I did a good job describing the situation. The two sub classes both have their own relationships that are unique. The ManyToMany relationships do not exist on the abstract class. Before I was getting these entities by having two FROM components and using LEFT JOIN to get the relationships. As I'm sure you know there can't be two FROM components with Doctrine's Paginator and I can't join on columns that do not exist in the abstract class or any of the sub classes.

Comment: I edited my original post to give the query builder that resulted in fewer queries but missing results

Comment: @ornj I'm afraid there's no real solution for that. What you can do is mapping those relations as `EXTRA_LAZY` ( http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#manytomany ). That will instantiate the collection ONLY when it is accessed. Also, consider removing bi-directional associations ( http://www.slideshare.net/guilhermeblanco/orm-dont-kill-your-db-developers-do )

Comment: Yeah I don't think going to Bi-directional associations will help at all, there isn't really a reason for those entities to be aware of the relationship. At this point I think my best bet is to query for each entity type separately and merge the results together.

Comment: is adding fetch="EAGER" to the entities a reasonable? Nearly every time I use one of these entities it is necessary for me to have information from the relationship but I can see why this would be considered a bad thing to do.

Comment: I wouldn't `fetch="EAGER"` since it doesn't guarantee that your operations will cause a fetch join at each access to the DB. Instead, I'd use either `fetch="EXTRA_LAZY"` (assuming the relation is not accessed often) or simply avoid the bidirectional association.

Comment: The relation is accessed often. I don't think EAGER is a bad way to go but I will have to be careful with it may be counter productive in cases where I don't need to load that association.